# React. Ошибка при импорте объекта (Attempted import error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

Стандартная схема: есть несколько файлов с объектами констант в одной папке, отправленные на экспорт в index.js для дальнейшего общего использования:

Файл userConstants.js

```
export const userConstants = {};
```

Файл itemConstants.js

```
export const itemConstants = {};
```

Файл index.js (использую абсолютные пути)

```
export * from 'constants/userConstants';
export * from 'constants/itemConstants';
```

Нужно получить константы только одного объекта, пытаюсь деструктурировать в файле компонента:

```
import { userConstants } from "constants";
```

Получаю ошибку:
Attempted import error: 'userConstants' is not exported from 'constants'.

Без деструктуризации ошибки нет. Также если объединить в 1 объект и экспортировать по дефолту, ошибка также есть в файле компонента, где я пытаюсь деструктурировать и получить определенный объект констант.

В чем может быть проблема? Данная схема использовалась в других проектах, но там использовались относительные пути. Может из-за этого webpack не может правильно собрать файлы?

Comment: вы уверены что "ваш абсолютный путь" указывает на нужные файлы? Я очень сомневаюсь что constants находится в корневом каталоге, из которого запускается программа. В любом случае приводите дерево каталогов, иначе на ваш вопрос трудно ответить.

Comment: constants находится в корневом каталоге, т.е. будет "src/constants".

Comment: Это не Деструктуризация.

Answer (score 2):

Webpack некорректно воспринимает в путях название папки "constants". Если назвать "_constants" ошибка будет исправлена.

Answer (score 0):

вместо

```
import { userConstants } from "constants";
```

надо

```
import  userConstants  from "constants";
```